# Как пройти по элементам от начального до конечного итератора, включая конечный?

Tags: c++, stl, итераторы

Есть два константных итератора (возврат `std::multimap::equal_range`), первый из которых указывает на начало последовательности (первый элемент), второй на последний элемент (**не на `end`, а именно на последний существующий элемент, с которым тоже необходимо работать**).

Вопрос: как в цикле пройтись по всем элементам, включая тот, на который указывает последний итератор?

Классический вариант

```cpp
for (std::multimap<T1, T2>::const_iterator i = range.first; i != range.second; ++i)
        // do stuff
```

где `range` – значение, возвращённое `std::multimap::equal_range` – пара константных итераторов. Не работает, т.к. не захватывает тот самый последний элемент, на который указывает `range.second`. Цикл идёт ДО него, но НЕ ВКЛЮЧАЯ его.

Итак, снова вопрос, более точно: как, желательно не костыльно, пройти с помощью представленных итераторов по всем элементам, включая тот, на который указывает последний итератор?

P.S. Использую C++ ДО 11ого стандарта (С++ 2003 вроде). Убедительно прошу не предлагать сменить стандарт на более новый, даже если это чем-то поможет, т.к. не имею такой возможности.

Используется Visual Studio 2008 SP1 на Windows 10 x64.

Comment: Странно. Документация говорит, что `range.second` - это не последний элемент в отрезке, а первый за ним. Так что должно работать.

Comment: Скорее всего, вы неверно трактуете работу [`equal_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range). Приведите [минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) описываемой вами "некорректной" его работы. Но если так необходимо, `i != next(range.second)`.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов почему тогда, если элемент один, у меня выполняется `range.second == range.first`? Возможно, я просто не понимаю, как это должно работать, если найден один элемент.

Comment: Возможно, это какая-то не совсем корректная реализация. Укажите в вопросе версию компилятора и ОС/платформу

Comment: @ГерманБорисов есть

Comment: пожалуйста, приведите минимальный воспроизводимый пример, т.к. на моей 2008й студии проблем не обнаружено